# Integration of product of logarithm

Tags: integration, logarithms, power-series, change-of-variable

For integration of
$ \int_0^1 (\log(1-u)^5)( \log(u)^5)/(u-1) du ,$
I have tried integral-by-parts, change of variable $ \log u =x $, and also expand it in series.
But I didn't get an answer. Could any one help me out?

Comment: I suppose that you want $[\log(1-u)]^5$, not $\log(1-u)^5=5\log(1-u)$, etc....

Comment: @Kelenner. I took is like $[\log(1-u)]^5$ too !

Comment: @YU MU What happened you lost interest in your problem!

Comment: @Kelenner  Yes, it is like $ [log(1-u)]^5$.

Comment: @ZAhmed It is the first time I use this. I didn't quite familiar to see the updates. Sorry about this, I will pay more attention to this next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx.$
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x)^5 \ln x^5}{x-1}dx=-25\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln x}{x}dx.~~~~(1)$$
Let us use polylog functions defined as $$\text{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^s}$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm
$$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} dx= -\text{Li}_2(x), \int \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x} dx= \text{Li}_3(x), \lim_{|x|\to 0} \text{Li}_s(x)=x$$
Let us do integration by parts of (1) taking $\ln x$ as first function, then
$$I=-25\left(\left . -\ln x \text{Li}_2(x)\right|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \text{Li}_2(x) dx\right)=-25~\text{Li}_3(x)|_{0}^{1}=-25 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}=-25 \zeta(3)$$

Comment: This is because you are integrating a different function :$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^5(1-x)\log^5 x}{x-1} dx$. Mind that the power 5 is on $\log$.  but  your question is different, it puts the power  5 on $(1-x)$  and $x$..

Comment: Sorry for that ! Being almost blind, I have too often this kind of mistake. I delete my answer and comment. Cheers :-(

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks @ZAhmed

Comment: @ZAhmed I am wondering if we can do the integral using $\Li_s(x)$ in this more complicated question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925889/further-question-on-logarithm-product-integral